# Output time with custom format (GMT instead UTC)

Tags: ruby, utc, gmt

I'm wondering how to get time in exactly this format using ruby 1.9.2:
I'm using rails 3.1 may be need to setup some environment constants to have it out of box with to_s method?

**2011-11-11 15:20:01 GMT+4**

instead

```
Time.now.to_s # => "2011-11-11 15:20:01 +0400"
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what you are getting at, since UTC and GMT are basically the same, can you clarify?

Comment: I guess 'GMT' feels more natural to many people from Europe. I grew up using 'GMT'. UTC feels more scientific/technical, albeit more correct when using it as a reference point for an offset.

Comment: i prepare xml for external service and they require exactly this format... i know UTC and GMT are basically same.... i export my data to xml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Time
  def to_gmt
    z = gmtoff / 3600
    strftime("%F %T GMT#{:+ if z>=0}#{z}")
  end
end

puts Time.now.to_gmt
#=> 2011-11-11 06:43:59 GMT-7
```

Comment: nice! where should i put this file (time.rb ) under rails to apply this monkey_patch?

Comment: i putted this file to initializers and now every things work as expected. thank you

Comment: This answer is wrong: Edge case:"2011-11-11 15:20:01 +1000" => "2011-11-11 15:20:01 GMT+1"

Answer (score 1):

```
Time.now.strftime("%D %T GMT%z")\
  .gsub(/GMT([-\+]\d\d\d\d)/){"GMT#{sprintf("%+d",$1.to_i/100)}"}
```

Comment: The date and time zone formats in this in this do not exactly match what the OP asked for.

Comment: your code produces "2011-11-11 17:45:31 GMT+0400" but i need "2011-11-11 17:45:31 GMT+4"

Comment: For me, `Time.now.strftime('%D')` returns `"11/11/11"`, not the desired `"2011-11-11"`.